# ORDER BY in both queries of the EXCEPT clause

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

I am loking to implement a paging query in ANSI SQL.

I tried the following query in SQL Server, but it did not allow it:

```
select top 20 * from MyTable order by id  
except
select top 10 * from MyTable order by id
```

But the following works fine:

```
select top 20 * from MyTable 
except
select top 10 * from MyTable order by id
```

e.g.:

```
input   expected result
20      11
11      13
25      14
6       16
4       17
2       18
1       19
9       20
3       25
7       
8       
16      
17      
18      
13      
14      
19      
10      
5
```

As seen from the above example, if we cannot write the first `ORDER BY` clause then the result will not be having the values 20, 11, 25.

Comment: Wow... `select *` is bad enough, but oh so much worse when we have no schema to work with.

Comment: @ebyrob I have used select * just to illustrate , it could be any thing other than *

Comment: @thunder nah, you do have enough info for a good answer here.  I'm just in a mood.

Comment: @stakx I am looking for something that works for all databases .

Comment: Actually, you’re off to a bad start with `TOP` which is not ANSI standard.

Answer (score 13):

I agree, this should work, `order by` in conjunction with `top` still produces a table (as oposed to just `order by` which produces a cursor and thus cannot be used as a select source).

Of course, you can work around this limitation easily:

```
select * from (select top 20 * from MyTable order by id) x
except
select * from (select  top 10 * from MyTable order by id) y
```

Answer (score 3):

the `order by` clause needs to appear only once, after the last-occurring query being compared by the `except` operator. `order by` is the last clause to be evaluated in the phases of logical query processing .

Comment: I added an example of why the order by is required in both queries

Comment: use `select...into` to insert the results of the `select top...order by` queries into a couple of temp tables. then perform the `except`.

Comment: temp tables seems to be viable option , but not so elegant isn't it ?or is it just my thinking.

Comment: @Thunder If you're worried about elegance, read the article I linked.  Notice the "elegant" triple-query is horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

This article dug out of the comment above is great:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6936/Paging-of-Large-Resultsets-in-ASP-NET

In particular the Asc-Desc method:

> This method uses default ordering in a subquery and then applies the
>   reverse ordering. The principle goes like this

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
    PK  /* PK Type */ NOT NULL PRIMARY 
)

INSERT INTO @temp 
SELECT TOP @PageSize PK FROM (
    SELECT TOP (@StartRow + @PageSize) 
    PK, 
    SortColumn /*If sorting column is defferent from the PK, SortColumn must 
             be fetched as well, otherwise just the PK is necessary */ 
    ORDER BY SortColumn /* default order – typically ASC */) 
ORDER BY SortColumn /* reversed default order – typically DESC */

SELECT ... FROM Table JOIN @Temp temp ON Table.PK = temp.PK 
ORDER BY SortColumn /* default order */
```

Of course performance isn't great, but it should work everywhere.

PS - I think you cheated, you got a paging answer *and* an `EXCEPT ORDER BY` answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might have been a comment, but the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) is a but subtle on this point and requires some explanation.

If you look at the [syntax definition](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) of the set operations (`union`, `union all`, `intersect`, `except`), you'll see that they reference "query_expression" and "query specification":

```
{ <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) } 
{ EXCEPT | INTERSECT }
{ <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) }
```

Logic would suggest that these are `select` statements in their full glory.  But they are not.  The full glory of the `select` statement includes four clauses not included in this:  `with`, `for`, `order by`, and `option`.  So, those are not allowed.

That said, I do think the above expression is not correct, because `<query_specification>` includes `into` as I read the documentation.  The more accurate specification would be the same as for `union`:

```
{ <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) } 
{ EXCEPT | INTERSECT }
{ <query_expression> }
```

I don't believe that `into` would be allowed on both parts of a query that uses a set operation.